# AWS S3, dont show image urls to the users (even in inspect element) but show the image with <img src="path/to/s3" /> tag

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

AWS S3, dont show image urls to the users (even in inspect element) but show the image with  tag

heard about presign urls but it shows keys.
I have below codes,

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('avatars/', $request->s3file, 'private');
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser is always going to show the source of the image. You could do something like use a service within laravel to 'mask' your S3 url by `<img src='/laravelpath/image.jpg'/>` then within PHP get the image from S3 and present to the user? You'd have the user's id with the request too.